# AFNetworking cancelAllOperations prevents batch completionBlock from firing

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I'm using `enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations` to submit a batch of requests.  If any of the requests fail, I want to immediately cancel any other requests that are still going.  To do so, I'm setting the failure callback on the individual operations to do a `[client.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];`.

This seems to cancel all remaining operations, but it's also preventing the overall completionBlock of the batch from executing...  Here's the code I'm trying to test this behavior with (one of the requests is always set to fail on the server).

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://arahlf.com"]];

NSMutableArray *requests = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    NSURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"echo.php" parameters:@{ @"sleep": @(i) }];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [client HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:nil failure:nil];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:nil failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Request failed, cancelling all operations.");
        [client.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
    }];

    [requests addObject:operation];
}

[client enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:requests progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
    NSLog(@"Progress: %i/%i", numberOfFinishedOperations, totalNumberOfOperations);

} completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
    NSLog(@"All done!");
}];
```

For me, the completionBlock is never executed.  Also, since one failing request cancels the remaining (which also fires the failure block), `cancelAllOperations` is getting executed many times actually.

Is there a better way to achieve this effect?

Comment: I can clearly understand the issues you are facing, but I am having trouble understanding what exactly is the desired effect, the goal you want to reach? A high-level description of your actual use case would be extremely helpful. (ie you have a batch of requests, what would you like to happen when it fails/succeeds?)

Comment: I'm performing a "data sync" of sorts, where about 10 requests are made to fetch various pieces of data.  Some of the requests take quite a while to complete.  If any of the requests fail, the sync itself has failed, and there's no reason to wait for the rest of the requests to finish (which could still be a while) so I want to cancel any requests that are still running.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it does. Now, you are successfully cancelling your requests instead of waiting. That part is working. But when you cancel them, part of your code isn't ever called (completion block) and part of it is called multiple times (failure block). What is exactly in those blocks that are causing the mentioned side effects to cause a problem?

Comment: Nothing, yet :)  I'm trying to create this as a proof of concept before I refactor my application to leverage AFNetworking + NSOperation/NSOperationQueue to make the sync requests.  The code I posted in my question exactly reproduces the problem.  The overall completion block of the batch request is never run.

Comment: Oh, my bad. So, even if the batch request is successful, the completion block is not triggered. That's clearly an issue worthy of submitting to their GitHub repo. Hopefully you'll get some luck submitting it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `operationQueue cancelAllOperations`, you are actually canceling the dependent operation that fires on batch completion, in addition to all of the other operations.

That is to say, in your example, 11 operations are cancelled: 10 network operations + the dependent batch completion operation.

The following change in `setCompletionblock:...` allows the batch completion to fire as expected:

```
[[client.operationQueue.operations filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
  return [evaluatedObject isKindOfClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
}]] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(cancel)];
```

Comment: Thanks.  I thought it might have something to do with that, but I wasn't sure whether or not canceling the dependent operations would've still triggered that or not.  On a side note, when canceling the requests, do I need worry about locking/synchronization at all?  It seems like all callbacks are running back on the main thread, but I'm a little unsure...